# django deployment on GCP with kubernetes

Tags: django, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I finally got my first django project and I need help in deploying it in GCP with kubernetes.
I've never deployed any project before so it's a bit frustrating for me with the client nagging on my head.
it's an E-learning platform so I want to use GCP with kubernetes (for CI/DI since there will be a lot of updates for the project) and Google cloud storage for storing media files.
i'd love to have some help concerning deployment, things to do/don't, and some useful links to start with.
ps: this is my first question so be easy on me

Comment: Umm... so what's that first question?

Comment: sorry, forgot to ask, my bad, i need someone to show me what to do and the best practices, i'm kinda stuck and idk where to start, i don't want to end up with a mess at the middle of project

Comment: Did you search for Google's quickstarts, tutorials, blog posts about Kubernetes? There's plenty of such stuff out there. Your question is too broad. Check out [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: i did search but couldn't find anything that covers the whole deployment process, i'll be grateful if you have some good resources. and sorry again for the bad question, i thinks i'm a bit frustrated since the guy who should be doing the deployment left everything to me (i have no experience with deployment at all)

Comment: I'm not much experienced with Kubernetes, but I guess I'd start here: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/kubernetes-engine

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, i'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too wide, try starting first and then asking a question - as we won’t be able to explain an universal way of deploying Django applications in GCP. I recommend starting from getting familiar with GCP services.

There is a really cool but paid course on Coursera platform ("[Getting Started with Google Kubernetes Engine](https://www.coursera.org/learn/google-kubernetes-engine)") with practical hands-on labs on how to use Kubernetes on GCP in pair with CI/CD tool like Jenkins. You can also find more about Jenkins in GCP in [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-kubernetes-engine).

You will also find there how to:

- Use different deployment strategies with Kubernetes (Rolling Updates,
  Canary and Blue-Green Deployments) with simple hello-world app.
- Create a continuous delivery pipeline using Jenkins

You can enroll into this course with free trial account.